# String have newline on php to unity

Tags: c#, php, string, unity-game-engine

```
if($action == "NewUser")
{
    $action ="INSERT INTO userdata VALUES ()";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$action);
    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $rename = "guest".$lastid;
    echo $rename;
}
```

$rename is string that I will use it to compare again in unity-c#

but the problem is
I'm try to use == and String.Equals() 
example
i'm got $rename by use unity www http and save it in string temp

```
if("guest11" == temp)
```

result is false;

```
if(String.Equals("guest11",temp))
```

result is false;

I'm doubt it have something after my string
I will try

```
temp +="myguess";
```

result should be `guest11guess`;

but it be

`guest11\nguess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely to be elsewhere in your PHP code or a quirk of Unity. Search your PHP files for any newlines after closing `?>` tags.

Otherwise, you can `temp.Replace("\n", "")`.